# Graphics diagnostics tools faild to install

Tags: windows, performance, visual-studio, debugging

I want to use Graphics diagnostics tools in c# application. In VS 2015 Community, Debug -> Perfomace profiler. Then I click to GPU Usage and start application. "The Graphics Tools opnational feature needs to be downloaded and installed". Ok. Error in installer: "The Graphics Tools faild to install. The DISM installer reported error 87". And [link](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=524999) to msdn how to solve a problem. I do all what I see in instruction, but there is a trouble at step 3. There is no components for installing. Why?

System: windows 10 corporate,
Version 1607,
Build 14393.447

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get the same issue because my machine is in a domain with some policy limits. After I remove the **WUServer value** from the registry key of **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate**, the Graphics Tools will be listed in Add New Features list.

Please check whether your machine is in a domain with some policy limits. If there has a WUServer value set, it means your machine is managed by the domain policy, please contact your company IT supporters to remove this limit.

Answer (score 1):

go regedit → HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\WindowsUpdate\AU and change UseWUServer to 0, after restart you will able to install Graphics Tools from Add or Remove Programs → Mange optional features → Add a feature. After successful installation change UseWUServer back to 1 and reboot your machine.

Answer (score 0):

To install graphics tools needs enable and start > **Firewall** and **Updates** at Windows Services. After all stop and disable this services.

Here guide how install >> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/use-the-directx-runtime-and-visual-studio-graphics-diagnostic-features

Or video at youtube >> https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=graphic+tools+windows